# MagicZoomPlus - Magento 1 - Tripling Images Error

Tags: magento, toolbox, magiczoomplus

Within Magento on Extention [MagicZoomPlus] by Magic Toolbox. When clicking an image for it to open in a lightbox, it seems to double, triple the first image.

An example can be found at https://www.missfloral.com/miss-floral-navy-bodaycon-plunge-lace-midi-dress.html

Looking in the backend, there is only of the image it is duplicating, happens on all products.

This extension is out the box so im unsure why this happening.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

try to flush magento image cache and see how this extension behaves. 
Looks like it creates thumbnails for different images in the same cache folder

D138_1_WEB_1.jpg, D138_1_WEB_2.jpg, D138_1_WEB_3.jpg etc.

can't give any further advice without a sneak peek into extension code

Comment: Thank you, However didn't solve the issue.But good point, might be worth me deleting the additional images manually and seeing it if does it again.

Comment: deleting catalog image cache would actually do this job.

Comment: Unfortunately, the image do regenerate when going to that product. Thank you for the help. Unless you may have another idea?

Comment: To bad this extension is commercial and a code review is not possible. How is the behaviour with other products? If it is different, try to create a new product with same data or to remove and reupload all images. Just guessing.